# Getting error while trying to install BadgeKit dependencies

Tags: node.js, mozilla, badge, openbadge

I try to install [BadgeKit](http://openbadges.org/) with this [manual](https://github.com/mozilla/openbadges-badgekit/wiki/BadgeKit-Self-Hosting-Guide#set-up-badgekit).

`npm install` dies with next [npm-debug.log](https://gist.github.com/SilentImp/927cdfb0204c12b992acf5d4dfde11fc#file-npm-debug-log).

`npm install --verbose 2>&1 | grep gyp` return [this](https://gist.github.com/SilentImp/927cdfb0204c12b992acf5d4dfde11fc#file-gyp-log).

Solution from topic «[npm install fails on node-gyp rebuild (using puppet)](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/115)» don't help me: --unsafe-perm don't did the trick.

> Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.5.0-x86_64-linode65 x86_64)
>
> $ node -v
>
> v6.0.0

May you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Solution was to install via nvm v0.10.24